# PersistableBundle setBoolean showing Min API Wrong

Tags: android-studio, bundle, android-jobscheduler, android-api-levels, jobservice

In Android Studio, while using PersistableBundle for jobSchedular,
In functions 'setBoolean', 'getBoolean', it is showing that minimum API required is API 22 but in Google Android Docs it shows that Min API is API 21.

Can Anyone one tell me if i am seeing it wrong or is there a Bug or what?

Thank You